# Conditionally include files i Xcode project

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a React Native project that has a dependency that requires a real device. I'd like to be able to run on a Simulator as well. I can easily use a preprocessor macro to avoid calling the dependency, but it won't build.

I know I should use a separate target, but this opens up a whole lot of other problems with React Native.

Is there any way to avoid including files in a target when building for a simulator?

Comment: In build settings there is an option to exclude files - "Excluded Source File Names", you can configure it for Simulator only. That might help you.

Comment: Thank you! That led me on the right path and I managed to fix it!